# I want to ask a question about using gerund after preposition

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Is this sentence right?

> "I angry at governing of the king on my country."

Comment: This sentence contains many errors.  You probably need the word "am" between "I" and "angry".  The prepositions are poorly chosen.  There are a few possible meanings, depending on which prepositions you choose to use.  Also, you might need to use the word "how" in this sentence.

Comment: It is possible that (after you add a verb and correct the prepositions) the use of the word "governing" might be correct.

Comment: Perhaps: I am angry about how the king governs my country.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more details to your question. Can you tell us what research you have done?

Answer (score 0):

As Jasper notes, there are several errors here.

The sentence has no verb. You probably mean "I AM angry ..."

"Governing" is a gerund as you say, which means that grammatically it is a noun. Here you are talking about one particular "governing", the governing of the king of your country. So you would need the article "the".

It is not the king who is being governed but the country or the people. We say "governing by" to indicate who is doing the governing, and "governing of" to way who or what is being governed.

Putting all that together, you COULD say, "I am angry at the governing of my country by the king". But for reasons I can't put my finger on, that's not a likely thing for a fluent speaker to say. We'd be more like to say, "I am angry at the way the king governs the country".

As to your original question, though, it certainly is legitimate to put a gerund after a preposition. "Bob failed at parenting," for example.